# Change toggle to open by default

Tags: javascript, css, toggle

I have a sidebar that opens when the menu icon is clicked and closed by clicking the X icon, I would like to reverse these actions so that the sidebar is open by default, I have tried poking around with the script but I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Any help appreciated!

```
<script>
function toggleNav() {
    var sidenav = document.getElementById("mySidenav"),
    main = document.getElementById("main");
    sidenav.style.width = sidenav.style.width === "300px" ? '0' : '300px';
    innerwrapper.style.marginLeft = innerwrapper.style.marginLeft === "300px" ? '0' :  '300px';
}   
</script>
```

CSS for the sidenav

```
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(7, 3, 17, 0.5);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}


@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

Toggle button code

```
<span style="font-size:16px;cursor:pointer" onclick="toggleNav()"><i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fas fa-times" title="Toggle Sidebar"></i></span>
```

mySidenav is the sidebar, innerwrapper is the content that gets shifted to the side when the sidebar is open.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use CSS classes.

For example, in your case you can create two classes:

- **.sidenav** for the default style of your sidenav (and when it is hidden)
- **.sidenav--open** for the specific style when your sidenav is open

Then you can alternatively add and remove the **sidenav--open** class to the sidebar element. To do this, you can use the [element.classList.toggle()](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp) JS method.

I think this is going to work:

```js
let sidenav = document.getElementById("sidenav");

function toggleSidenav() {
  sidenav.classList.toggle("sidenav--open");
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-top: 60px;
  background: rgba(7, 3, 17, 0.5);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sidenav--open {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 300px;
}


@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="sidenav" class="sidenav sidenav--open"></div>

<span style="font-size:16px;cursor:pointer" onclick="toggleNav()">
  <i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fas fa-times" title="Toggle Sidebar"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: No joy, the sidenav isn't appearing. Not sure if Jcink just has a mind of it's own and hates me tonight or what's happening!

Comment: If you want to display the sidebar by default, you just have to add the **sidenav--open** class to the sidebar HTML element.  

I've updated the code above